# Authenticating to RDP using keys

Tags: remote-desktop, authorization

is it possible to authenticate for RDP using keys (the same way as in SSH)? I have tons of machines I need RDP to, and I'm tired of keeping the password list somewhere (they aren't part of domain, so I cannot use my domain account).

Comment: Not an answer, but perhaps check out [Terminals](http://terminals.codeplex.com/).  It's got a decent connection/credential manager system.

Comment: Terminals has been migrated to GitHub (https://github.com/terminals-Origin/Terminals), and is no longer under development.

Answer (score 0):

Keepass can do this.  You can also save the credentials with the connection, of course, though I assume that you wouldn't want to do that (for obvious security reasons.)  It is also possible to set the RDP file to save credentials after the first time you've authenticated.